# Obj-C: How to get and call a block argument from NSInvocation - stubbing Twitter account on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, objective-c-blocks, ocmock

I'm testing an iOS application using KIF and OCMock, stubbing the device's `ACAccountStore` to return my own representation of a Twitter account. I want to stub `requestAccessToAccountsWithType`, and call the passed completion handler with my own values, but I can't seem to get the block from the invocation and call it properly (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`). Being new to Objective-C and iOS, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong while pulling the block out of the `NSInvocation`.

**This is the production code.** The _accountStore is injected from the test setup.

```
ACAccountType *twitterType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:twitterType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"authorized=%i in block", granted);
    // important code here
}];
```

**Test setup code.**

```
ACAccountStore *realStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
// Stub the store to return our stubbed Twitter Account
id mockStore = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:realStore];
[[[mockStore stub] andDo:^(NSInvocation *invocation) {
    void (^grantBlock)(BOOL granted, NSError *error) = nil;
    [invocation getArgument:&grantBlock atIndex:1]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    grantBlock(TRUE, nil); // run the important code with TRUE
}] requestAccessToAccountsWithType:[OCMArg any] withCompletionHandler:[OCMArg any]];
// not shown: inject the mockStore into production code
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should be using an index of 3, not 1.  Index 0 is `self`, and index 1 is `_cmd`.

Comment: Thanks! This is documented, I just missed it: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html